Debezium TImeout Exception while fetching metadata
I am trying to set up debezium oracle source connector, but facing issues with the error message Timeout Exception while fetching Metadata.
These are the configurations:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "name":"debe_source_connector", "config":{ "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "connection.url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:test", "table.include.list": "DB_Schema.CONSUMER", "database.server.name": "server1", "database.tablename.case.insensitive": "true", "database.hostname": "localhost", "database.port": "1523", "database.user": "user", "database.password": "password", "database.dbname": "test", "message.key.columns": "test.CONSUMER:ID" , "transforms":"unwrap", "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState", "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false", "time.precision.mode":"connect", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka-headless:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "debe_history","schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka-headless:9092", "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic":"debe_schema","database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true", "database.history.store.only.captured.tables.ddl": "true", "include.schema.changes": "true", "snapshot.mode": "initial", "errors.log.enable": "true", "topic.prefix": "DB_Schema" }}' http://localhost:8083/connectors

kafka connect properties files:
"plugin.path": "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
  "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  "config.storage.replication.factor": "1"
  "offset.storage.replication.factor": "1"
  "status.storage.replication.factor": "1"
  "security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"admin\" password=\"test\";"
  "producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "producer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"ConnectProducer\"  password=\"test\";"
  "consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required  username=\"ConnectConsumer\" password=\"test\";"
  "database.history.kafka.topic": "debe_history"
  "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka-headless:9092"
  "database.history.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"ConnectConsumer\"  password=\"test\";"
  "database.history.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"ConnectProducer\"  password=\"test\";"
  "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka-headless:9092"
  "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "debe_schema"
  "schema.history.internal.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"ConnectConsumer\"  password=\"test\";"
  "schema.history.internal.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
  "schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN"
  "schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"ConnectProducer\"  password=\"test\";"

JDBC source connector works fine, but debezium is not working properly. What can be the issue here?
I have cross checked configurations, and added configurations for topics that are configured in debezium properties.
JDBC source oracle connector works fine.
EDIT
More logs
[2024-04-15 14:48:13,382] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=debe_source_connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
[2024-04-15 15:07:05,486] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=debe_source_connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)

